# Doing comparisons from two null distributions

Tags: resampling

I have a situation where I have an observed statistic computed from data, and then I have approximated the null distribution by some sort of resampling. I have used this to calculate p-values for a one-sided hypothesis test.

Now, if I want to do a comparison between two statistics (are they significantly different?), but I already have the samples from the two null distributions, is there some way to use these to approximate the null distribution for the difference?

Comment: The statistics are independent, I suppose?

Comment: Yes they are independent.

Comment: Although you refer to "two null distributions," your description encompasses only one: the one created by "some sort of resampling."  What is the second null distribution to which you refer?  (The very concept of multiple "null distributions" seems inconsistent with the definition of a null distribution, so your help in clarifying what you are asking would be appreciated.)

Answer (score 1):

Provided both the distributions of the single test statistics follow their null distributions, you can base on the convolution of them (of course, with one distribution reflected on the y-axis). This could be approximated by the convolution of the approximations. Computationally, if `-x1` (reflected) and `x2` are the vectors of the values of the resampled statistics, then `as.vector(t(-x1)%*%x2)` is the vector of the convolution's values.

If you can not assume that both null distributions hold, then you can not use the resampled distributions unless other assumptions help you out.